# How do I create a constraint for this url route?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, url-routing

```
   routes.MapPageRoute("View Home Page",
        "{homepage}",
        "~/home.aspx",
        true,
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "homepage", "national" } },
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "region", "^(national|bc|ab|on){0,1}$" } }
       );
```

I only want the route to match urls such as http://www.mydomain.com/national, http://www.mydomain.com/bc, http://www.mydomain.com/ab, or http://www.mydomain.com/on

How do I construct the constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom constraint, so my code now looks like so:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("View Home Page",
        "{region}/default.aspx",
        "~/home.aspx",
        true,
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "region", "national" } },
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "region", new HomePageConstraint() } }
       );
```

and the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for HomePageConstraint
/// </summary>
public class HomePageConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return GetRegions().Any(x => x.ToLower() == values[parameterName].ToString().ToLower());

    }


    private List<string> GetRegions()
    {
        List<string> set = new List<string>();
        set.Add("National");
        set.Add("BC");
        set.Add("AB");
        set.Add("SASK");
        set.Add("MAN");
        set.Add("ON");
        set.Add("QC");
        set.Add("Maritimes");
        set.Add("NL");

        return set;

    }
}
```

Works great (I'm using webforms and not mvc - I'm sure it works in both instances).  Found the how to here: http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No responses yet so I'll let you know what I've done. Unfortunately, the routing engine for ASP.NET MVC isn't the greatest.

You'll need to change appropriate variables to match your routing and views, but this should get you started.

Put this as the *last* route you're mapping:

```
routes.MapRoute("Root", "{pathName}", new
{ 
    controller = "Root", 
    action = "Default"
});
```

And in your controller:

```
public class RootController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Default(string pathName)
    {
        // No pathName? 

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pathName)) {
            return this.View("~/Views/Root/home.aspx")
        }

        // Check to see if there's a view for the pathName

        var viewPath = String.Format("~/Views/Root/{0}.aspx", pathName);

        if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(viewPath))) {
            return this.View(viewPath);
        }

        // Not found

        this.Response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        return this.View("~/Views/404.aspx");
    }

}
```

You're therefore then going to have to name your views after what "pathNames" you expect:

- ~/Views/Root/national.aspx
- ~/Views/Root/ab.aspx
- ~/Views/Root/bc.aspx
- etc.

It's not too bad if you don't mind having conventions like this.